# How do I execute a proc with a delay in nim?

Tags: asynchronous, timeout, delay, nim-lang

I was looking to get a bit more into async in nim with the C-backend and have a fair bit of experience with Javascript. There functionality such as `setTimeout` is available to execute a function at a later time.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("Potato"), 1000)
```

What does the equivalent in nim look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a quick solution, just go with 1). If you're curious about the async fundamentals, read the entire post.

### 1) With Async Syntax + SleepAsync

The simplest one is just using an async proc and `sleepasync`:

```
import std/asyncdispatch

proc afterX(wait: int) {.async.} =
  await sleepAsync(wait)
  echo "Stuff Happened"

let future: Future[void] = afterX(500)

... You can do more stuff in between getting the future and waiting for it ...

waitFor future
```

The `async` pragma changes the proc to return a `Future` of whatever it was returning. In this case nothing, so `void`. This future in your "global", synchronous context you can then just `waitFor`.

Note that `waitFor` is not similar to JS `await`. JS has no equivalent to it as it does not have this level of access to the context it is executed in. `waitFor` is for waiting for a task to complete **outside** of an async-context and it *will* block the thread to do so. Nim's `await` is what functions the same as JS's `await` and that can only be used within async procs.

### 2) Without Async Syntax: addTimer

Nim has a proc [setTimer](https://nim-lang.org/docs/asyncdispatch.html#addTimer%2Cint%2Cbool%2CCallback) which you might stumble over if you search for timeout-related keywords in the docs.

That does what we want, but with very different, more low-level syntax, that functions almost the same as 1:

```
import std/asyncdispatch

let echoMe: Callback = proc(fd: AsyncFD): bool =
  echo "Stuff Happened"
  return true

addTimer(500, true, echoMe)

... You can do more stuff in between registering the callback and polling for it ...

poll()
```

`AsyncFD` here is `AsyncFileDescriptor` (or Handle on Windows). When doing async IO operations, this parameter is filled with the handle to whatever that IO operation is being done on. Not relevant for us in this scenario, but useful to know.

AddTimer "registers" the `echoMe` proc on a the dispatcher (the sort of event-loop) to execute later.
`poll` then fetches that proc and executes it.

As an aside and not relevant for the discussion:

The boolean used by `addTimer` defines whether `echoMe` should be removed from the dispatcher/event-loop after it was executed the first time. So `false` means to execute it over and over again with time delays in between.

The boolean returned by `echoMe` **also** defines whether it should deregistered from the dispatcher/event-loop, but does so after every execution. This only matters if `addTimer` was given `true` for its boolean in the first place. So `true` from `echoMe` means "Even if I am allowed to execute over and over, stop that now, deregister me from the event-loop".

### Why are these two the same? They look different!

When poll fetches a proc, it blocks the thread until it can get a task or until it times out. Which is eerily similar to waitFor. That is because waitFor is just a disguised call to `poll` run in a while-loop until the `future.finished` boolean flips from "false" to "true".

Both of these do what we want, albeit async does it with nicer syntax:

- Register a task (`echoMe`) on a queue via a "task dispatcher" (The `async` pragma / `addTimer`) to execute later. [The dispatcher functions as a sort-of event-loop](https://nim-lang.org/docs/asyncdispatch.html).
- Enable you to do whatever you want in the meantime
- Force you to fetch the task from the queue (`poll`, `waitFor`) and execute it implicitly

The main difference is that with the Async-Syntax, waiting for N milliseconds is part of the task itself (it is within `echoMe` via `sleepAsync`), while with `addTimer` the waiting is done *before* the task is executed during polling.